# Current tranformer, burden resistor calculation

Tags: current, transformer

I have 1:50 wound current transformer and I don't have the datasheet. Could anybody help me to calculate the burden resistor?

[image: photo of burden transformer]

Maximum current to be measured: 2A

Max output voltage to ADC: 5V

Comment: Please put forth the effort to capitalize, use punctuation, and write as though you actually care about getting an answer.

Comment: What are you using the CT to measure? What range of input is the CT measuring? What device are you applying the output of the CT to? What range of voltages can that device tolerate?

Comment: @Li-aungYip measure AC current max 2A;output of CT to be connected with ADC I/P of arduino

Comment: What biasing arrangement are you using to interface the CT to your MCU?

Comment: To clarify @Andyaka 's comment - your Arduino ADC input is rated for 0V - 5V. If you apply an AC signal directly to your ADC pin, it will spend half of each AC cycle with a negative voltage and you will damage the ADC.

Comment: Also, is your "2 amp" input 2A RMS, or 2A peak, or 2A peak-to-peak? What are your frequencies of interest? (50Hz? 60Hz? 400Hz? 2kHz?)

Comment: @Andyaka i thought of using a rectifier and filter arrangement for giving input to ADC

Comment: @Li-aungYip 2A Peak-to-Peak current and frequency is 50Hz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 2 Ap-p flowing through your primary, the secondary current would be: -

\$\dfrac{2 Ap-p}{50}\$ = 40 mAp-p. If you used a 1 ohm burden resistor you'd get 40 mVp-p which wouldn't be enough to drive a bridge rectifier (diodes need about 0.6 V across them to conduct).

What is worth a try is feeding the output of your C.T. strainght into a bridge and then putting the burden resistor on the output of the bridge. This may work fine but I have a doubt.

A C.T. is a step up transformer and if the voltage dropped on the primary single turn is 10 mVp-p (for 2 Ap-p flowing) then the output voltage will only be 500 mVp-p open circuit and not enough to drive a bridge.

If you wanted it to work, you could still use a 1 ohm (or whatever the manufacturer recommends in their data sheet for the burden resistor) and then use an op-amp precision rectifier to boost the 40 mVp-p AC voltage across the burden to some more usable DC value.

If you are using the signal from the C.T. to calculate power then you can't use a bridge or any rectifier because the AC waveforms of current and voltage need to be multiplied together and then averaged in your MCU.

Here's a brief reason why the burden resistor has to be about 1 ohm or less on the OP's CT: -

[image]

It's a little more complex than this in that the secondary copper loss and leakage inductance are also in series with the burden and this adds another small error - it's a linear error so it isn't too bad but it can account for several percent of the signal. The upshot of all this is make the burden as low as is practically possible - use op-amps to bring the signal back to something that is usable.

Better CTs have higher turns ratios to avoid the fall-off in signal due to the magnetizing inductance not being thoroughly shunted by the relected impedance of the burden on the primary.

Comment: can you suggest me a circuit to interface CT with arduino

Comment: In my world (power engineering) CT's are step-*down* devices, i.e. for scaling a 1,200 A primary current down to a more manageable 1 A current. Are small CT's like this *usually* step-*up*?

Comment: @li-aung in terms of voltage it is a step up device. It's like any other transformer, a small voltage across the primary will get magnified by the step up turns ratio and of course the current gets stepped down.

Comment: I don't know muuch about CTs, but any reason you couldn't use say a 100 ohm resistor for a 4V p-p output? I would have thought there was only a risk using a lower resistance than the manufacturer recommends.

Comment: @PeterJ a CT is a voltage transformer as much as it is a current transformer - with an unloaded output the maximum voltage it can generate is based on the small volt drop across the primary magnetizing inductance (micro henries); 1 turn on primary magnifies that volt drop to 50x on secondary. When a burden is applied, the magnetizing inductance gets shunted by a resistor that is turns-ratio-squared lower than the burden BUT if the burden is too big it cannot exceed the open circuit voltage of the secondary.

Comment: @yogece - are you trying to measure circuit power or are you only interested in an approximation to RMS current? Maybe you are interested in precise RMS current?

Comment: @Andyaka, ahh yes thanks hadn't thought about it in that way

Comment: @Andyaka RMS current only

Comment: @yogece if you wish to measure RMS current accurately then you need to sample the waveform produced by the burden at a significant rate to account for harmonics in the current waveform. I don't know what these might be of course and quite possibly you don't either. Go for at least the 15th harmonic of 50Hz and then sample 3 times faster than this - if using 50Hz this means sampling at below 500us. Each sample needs to be squared then totalized then averaged to give reasonable RMS. Or use an RMS to DC converter chip.

Comment: Did you find this answer useful? Remember the little comment I left yesterday?